# Top border appears over left border in css

Tags: css, border

I need a left border size of 20px and a top border of 1px;

The snippet above:

```
border-left:20px solid #ff0000;
border-top:1px solid #4f5565;
```

will actually produce this:

[image: border problem]

As you see, the top border appears over the left border.

How is it possible fix that?

Comment: What behavior would you like to display? Where the two borders meet at an angle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the `div`:

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

The following will enable a left border that overlaps *above* the top border:

```
.container {
    border-top: 1px solid #4f5565;
    border-left:0;
    position:relative; /* Limits the :before declaration to the bounds of the element */
}
.container:before {
    content:"\00a0"; /* Escaped unicode for a non-blank space */
    border-left:20px solid #ff0000;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top: -1px;
}
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bR4ec/1).

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so.  You could use the left-border style and for the top border use an image.

ie.

```
<style>
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-left: 20px solid #ff0000;
    background: url(images/2x2dot.jpg) 20px top repeat-x;
}
</style>
```